i want to create one docker file for next.js monorepo
this is my project structure in monorepo and i have dist folder after build project-3.
i created docker file for project-3 , but it is too large so what is solution for decrease size of docker file in monorepo nextjs project-3 , thanks.
i tried below docker image
project 
 |-- apps
      |-- project-1
      |-- project-2
      |-- project-3


# stage 1 - build the app with nx and copy the necessary files to the final image
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:16-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm install --global nx@latest\
    && nx run project-3:build

# stage 2 - copy the necessary files from the builder image to the final image
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder ./app/dist/apps/project-3 ./app/
COPY --from=builder ./app/next-config-canvas.js ./app/next.config.js

# Install Nx CLI globally in the final image
RUN npm install --global nx@latest

# Set environment variables
ENV NEXTAUTH_URL: ${NEXTAUTH_URL}

# Expose the port your application runs on
EXPOSE 4202

# Start the application
CMD ["sh", "-c", "nx run project-3:serve:production"]


also i want to copy necessary file in docker image to create image.

"it is too large" - what does that mean? Are you facing any specific error?

it is too large means  , docker image size is too large [3.45 GB] when i build it.
so can you suggest me what can i do for decrease size of image and for that what file will be copy from the builder to build image?
